# How do I extract the "message" value from elasticsearch? (DSL)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

How do I extract the "message" value from elasticsearch? (DSL)

I tried it. (my code)

-> I want to extract all the "message" values only.

```
GET 0503instgram_csv/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "message",
      "query": ?????????????
    }
  }
}
```

[image]
-> I want to process the data by saving new field values of all "message" that are printed out.

I'd really appreciate your help.

@ESCoder
This is a picture of the result of the attempt as you said.
[image]

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 281,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "0503instgram_csv",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "zbKQMXkB98wUkKJOL8dT",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "message" : "\"lovablepoetree"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "0503instgram_csv",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "zrKQMXkB98wUkKJOL8dU",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "message" : """내가 아는 사람 중에 최고 셀럽(@hanstar.kim)과 맥주 마심셀럽과 술이라니....! 성공해따 나자신!!!!!! 그래놓고 사진은 나 혼자 찍어따^.^ 다음번엔 투샷을 찍어보쟈......"""
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "0503instgram_csv",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "z7KQMXkB98wUkKJOL8dU",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "message" : """..열정을 응원 합니다. 도대현 드림❤️❤️❤️"""
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "0503instgram_csv",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "0LKQMXkB98wUkKJOL8dU",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "message" : "lovablepoetree"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "0503instgram_csv",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "0bKQMXkB98wUkKJOL8dj",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "message" : """좋아요 69개
"""
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "0503instgram_csv",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "0rKQMXkB98wUkKJOL8dj",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "message" : """['paulchang1103,Paul Chang (장준성),passionated_man,도대현,luv_____juju,쥬쥬,koonge01,영이,p.s.j___5959,또둔,panchitoyoon,Ye Suk Yoon,hyeriiing__,혤,sunny.gibbab,써니네식탁(sunny Gib-bab),_wjstn_ry_02,전수교(20),sungwoon_jinsik,윤성운,t_a_k_3014,케이,팔로우']
"""
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "0503instgram_csv",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "07KQMXkB98wUkKJOL8dj",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "message" : "passionated_man"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "0503instgram_csv",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1LKQMXkB98wUkKJOL8dj",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "message" : "1일"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "0503instgram_csv",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1bKQMXkB98wUkKJOL8dj",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "message" : """..열정을 응원 합니다. 도대현 드림❤️❤️❤️"""
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "0503instgram_csv",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1rKQMXkB98wUkKJOL8dj",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "message" : """1일답글 달기","lovablepoetree"""
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html) to extract only `message` field values

```
GET/_search
{
  "_source": [
    "message"
  ]
}
```

**Update 1:**

You can use the [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-filter-source), to store only the field values of the `message` field in a different index

```
POST /_reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "old-index",
    "_source": ["message"]
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new-index"
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated the post about the result of the way you said.

However, my purpose is to extract and save all the values of "message".

What should I do?

Comment: @인제김 do you want to save the value of the `message` field in some other field?

Comment: I want to extract all the values of the message and save them in one place.

Comment: Posting Updating.

Comment: @인제김 please go through the updated part of the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?